# Найти все метки на ru.stackoverflow. Ускорение работы функции с помощью multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, stackexchange-api

Что нужно заменить вместо **?** , чтобы мультипроцесс заработал ?

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def all_marks():
    x = 1
    TAGS_ADDRESS = 'https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags?page=' + str(x) + '&tab=popular'
    req_all_marks = requests.get(TAGS_ADDRESS)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req_all_marks.text, 'lxml')
    links = soup.find_all('span', class_='page-numbers')
    pages = []
    for link in links:
        pages.append(link.text)
    last_page = str(pages[6])
    y = 1
    while y != int(last_page):
        TAGS_ADDREZZ = 'https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags?page=' + str(y) + '&tab=popular'
        req_all_markz = requests.get(TAGS_ADDREZZ)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(req_all_markz.text, 'lxml')
        marks = soup.find_all('a', class_='post-tag')
        for mark in marks:
            print(mark.text)
        y += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p:
        p.map(all_marks, ?)
```

Comment: Словами что вы хотите сделать: ускорить один вызов all_marks() либо  запустить all_marks() в 5 процессах (зачем?)

Comment: я б запустил функцию не в пуле, а вот в пул засунул p.map(all_marks, pages[6]). тоесть выборка списка страниц, а потом распараллеливаем вайл

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы ускорить работу `all_marks()` функции, рассмотрите возможность использования API, которое сразу нужную информацию может вернуть, без web-scraping. Попробуйте готовые обёртки такие как [Py-StackExchange](https://stackapps.com/questions/198/py-stackexchange-an-api-wrapper-for-python), к примеру, чтобы напечатать через пробел все метки на сайте:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import stackexchange  # $ pip install py-stackexchange

site = stackexchange.Site('ru.stackoverflow.com', impose_throttling=True)
for tag in site.all_tags():
    print(tag.name, end=' ')
```

или [Stack.PY](https://stackapps.com/questions/3417/stack-py-a-python-module-for-accessing-the-stack-exchange-2-1-api), итд. [Пример](https://stackapps.com/a/4113/10006):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import itertools
import stackpy  # $ pip install stackpy

site = stackpy.Site('ru.stackoverflow')
for page in itertools.count(1):
    tags = site.tags.page(page)
    print(*tags)
    if not tags['has_more']:
        break
```

Или руками http запросы выполните: [пример](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4126/23044).

Чтобы выполнить разные части `all_marks()` функции параллельно, разбейте её на несколько частей (не тестировано):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool # use threads

with Pool(4) as pool:
    last_page = get_tags_last_page_number()
    results = pool.imap_unordered(get_tags_from_page, range(1, last_page + 1))
    for page, tags, error in results:
        if error is None:
            print(" ".join(tags))
        else:
            sys.stderr.write("failed to download tags"
                             " from {page} with {error}\n".format(**vars()))
```

Обратите внимание:

- используются потоки (производительность вероятно IO ограничена, поэтому процессы не нужны — можно переключить на процессы, изменив import, чтобы проверить)
- печать происходит только в основном потоке: `get_tags_from_page()` ничего не печатает, а только возвращает результат (найденные метки) или ошибку:

```
def get_tags_from_page(page):
    try:
        # get tags here...
        return page, tags, None
    except Exception as e:
        return page, None, str(e)
```

Чтобы попробовать ещё раз в случае ошибки, иногда может быть [удобней concurrent.futures использовать (похожая функциональность)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example).

Можно измерить, что произойдёт в вашем случае, если вообще всё в одном потоке скачивать, используя пул соединений, [к примеру с помощью `aiohttp.ClientSession()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31795242/4279).

Answer (score 0):

Вот так?:

```
import itertools


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p:
        for _ in p.map(all_marks, itertools.cycle(())):
            pass
```