# Как смотреть пришло тебе сообщение или ответ в ru.stackoverflow.com через requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, stackexchange-api

Можно ли сделать скрипт на *python*, использующий модуль `requests` (почему именно requests: ну потому что он легкий и я его немного знаю, если есть другие варианты - то предлагайте) для того чтобы смотреть новые сообщения в `ru.stackoverflow.com`? Скорее не смотреть, а узнавать что они есть.

Используется Python 3.6.1

**Можно ли это сделать? Если можно то как?**

Comment: Посмотреть [api у стека](https://api.stackexchange.com/), если там есть такая возможность, то использовать api, иначе парсить. Пример [использования api](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/6c64ecb4a6cea678892edd0a6db2bbc23d7e020e/ru_stackoverflow_exception_questions/gatherer.py). Пример [запроса к api](https://clck.ru/ByLpk).

Comment: неофициально, можно посмотреть на [счётчик непрочитанных входящих сообщений](https://stackexchange.com/topbar/get-unread-counts). Если `UnreadInboxCount` не нулевой, то что-то есть. Если нулевой, то или нет ничего нового или вы не залогинены. Можно с помощью официального API на [содержимое непрочитанных сообщений посмотреть](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/inbox-unread) (OAuth 2.0). Самое сложное это authentication правильно выполнить в каждом случае.

Comment: @jfs можно поподробней насчёт официального API

Comment: @jfs что такое  API key и если вам не сложно сделайте пожалуйста ответ на этот вопрос с подробным объяснением.

Comment: @jfs я задал отдельный вопрос по этой теме, если вам не сложно, отетьте пожалуйста https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/729556/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0-api-stackexchange-com-docs-inbox-unread

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Чтобы узнать есть ли непрочитанные входящие сообщения для Stack Overflow пользователя, идентифицируемого с помощью `access_token`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
import requests

url = ('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/me/inbox/unread'
       + '?key=' + os.environ['SO_KEY']
       + '&access_token=' + os.environ['SO_TOKEN']
       + '&site=stackapps')
r = requests.get(url)
r.raise_for_status()
items = r.json()['items']
has_unread = len(items) > 0
if has_unread:
    assert next((True for x in items if x['is_unread']), False)
    print('there are unread items')
else:
    print('nothing new')
sys.exit(not has_unread)  # success if there are unread items
```

Скрипт использует [`/me/inbox/unread` метод из Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-unread-inbox). По ссылке документация и живой пример (нажмите на "Get Token" и "Run" кнопки, чтобы результат вызова API увидеть).

Параметр `site` требуется в этом запросе, но все непрочитанные входящие сообщения со всех сайтов возвращаются.

Для работы необходимо, чтобы `SO_KEY` и `SO_TOKEN` переменные окружения содержали API ключ и `access_token` соответственно.

API ключ это просто уникальный идентификатор для вашего приложения, которое stackexchange API использует ([при регистрации вашего приложения выдаётся этот ключ](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register)). Информация из `/2.2/inbox/` не доступна анонимным пользователям, поэтому необходим ещё `access_token` (что требует наличие API ключа). Также ключ увеличивает кол-во разрешённых запросов к API и для запросов, не требующих [authentication](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication) (<-- по ссылке описано как `access_token` получить в зависимости от вида приложения).

Чтобы освоиться с Stack Overflow API, можно выполнить вызовы, которые не требуют аутентификации, [пример](https://gist.github.com/zed/fa058fe71ac946a569bd75a43270fbf5). И/или воспользоваться готовыми библиотеками типа py-stackexchange, [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/705722/23044).