# Как открыть сайт в консоли и манипулировать HTML кодом на открытой странице

Tags: python

Как открыть сайт и манипулировать `HTML` кодом на открытой странице? Я хочу, например, открыть сайт [OK.RU](http://www.ok.ru), и передать логин и пароль от учётной записи. Я не хочу открывать браузер, хочу именно, через консоль.

Comment: А перед несколькими десятками высококлассных специалистов, работающих в Mail.Ru Group стоит задача недопустить этого. Удачи.

Comment: Протокол HTTP вам в помощь с его методами GET и POST. Смотрите на сетевую активность при работе через браузер, потом реализовываете ее же на Питоне.

Comment: это зависит от конкретного сайта. Удобней API использовать если есть,  [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/729167/23044). В противном случае: requests, selenium webdriver, scrapy (+splash for javascript), phantomjs, [headless] chrome (puppeteer).

Comment: @jfs я добавлю немного оффтопа. Посоветуйте библиотеку для воспроизведения поточного аудио, пожалуйста. Вопрос открывать не хочется, а Вы, я думаю, знаете как это сделать. Мне хватит названия.(лучше, чтобы она была менее массивной)

Comment: @MrMorgan: в моём профиле, есть почта. Не обещаю, что отвечу. Полезно посмотреть на https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour (какая информация необходима, чтобы на подобный вопрос информативный ответ получить).