# Отсутствует тело GET запроса при попытке получения токена от vk

Tags: python, django

Задача - написать веб-приложение на Django, на котором можно зарегистрироваться через ВК и на странице пользователя будет отображаться 5 друзей.
Для этого нужно получить токен. Пользуюсь вот этой инструкцией: https://vk.com/dev/implicit_flow_user
Перехожу по ссылке:
"https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=6481880&display=page&redirect_uri=http://warkb.pythonanywhere.com/userpage&scope=friends&response_type=token&v=5.75&state=123456"
где client_id - id приложения. После чего происходит редирект на url c токеном:
http://warkb.pythonanywhere.com/userpage#access_token=*****************************************&expires_in=86400&user_id=263728812&state=123456
Но это только в адресной строке браузера. В Django я отлавливаю пакет, но словарь GET в нем пуст. View-функция

```
# urls.py
url(r'^userpage', views.userpage, name='userpage')

# views.py
def userpage(request):
    user_id = request.GET.get('user_id', 'nodata')
    access_token = request.GET.get('access_token', 'nodata')
    return HttpResponse('user_id: %s, token: %s' % (user_id, access_token))
```

Возвращает
user_id: nodata, token: nodata

Comment: фраза "тело GET запроса" в контексте http обычно другое означает. У вас тут проблема с разницой между query и fragment частями url (никакого отношения к http GET body). Вы пытаетесь данные url query достать (после `?`), а они в url fragment (после `#`)

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Как тогда получить этот фрагмент? Я пробовал воспользоваться HTTPRequest.get_full_path(), но он мне возвращает url до решетки.

Comment: как в контексте django view получить часть после `#` в url, можно как отдельный Stack Overflow вопрос спросить¶ Получив `'a=b&c=d'` строку, можно ещё один вопрос задать, как её распарсить (достаточно stdlib), можно не делать акцент на django¶  Объединив ответы на эти вопросы, можно для текущего вопроса ответ написать.

Comment: Получить аргументы - это уже ерунда. Два split и два if. А вот с хешом действительно проблема. Я нашел ответ на StackOverflow на первый вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181186/how-to-access-url-hash-fragment-from-a-django-request-object Если в двух словах - никак. В любом случае - спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Есть более надёжный метод, чем руками split делать и вопросы на Stack Overflow существуют, чтобы не только автор решение мог найти.  [~95% трафика из поисковиков на Stack Overflow](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7374/23044)

Comment: Создал новый вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/830933/Как-достать-данные-из-url-fragment-в-django?noredirect=1#comment1327586_830933

Comment: я ошибся (`#` часть может не дойти до django view). Поэтому "объединив ответы" не получится в данном случае ответ дать. Чтобы на текущий вопрос ответить, возможно нужно другой режим auth (с участием сервера) выбрать.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, что вы понимаете под выбрать другой режим auth? Нужно изменить какую-то настройку в settings.py или что-то другое?

Comment: с vk не помню, а вот (вероятно аналогичные) способы auth для [stackexchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication), [пример использования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/729167/23044)  (вы похоже для vk сами нашли)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во вконтакте есть несколько методов получения токена. Для веб-приложения нужен вот этот - https://vk.com/dev/authcode_flow_user
Тот метод, которым пользовался я, а именно Implicit Flow, предназначен для работы с api только из приложений, запущенных непосредственно с устройства. Думаю, решетка как раз таки была нужна для того, чтобы этим методом не пользовались из веб-приложений.