# Как достать данные из url fragment в Django

Tags: python, django, url

После перенаправления на django сервер приходит запрос с url вида:
http://warkb.pythonanywhere.com/userpage#parm1=value1&parm2=value2&parm3=value3
Нужно достать значения после #. В HTTPRequest.GET они отсутствуют. Как их можно достать?

Comment: Вроде бы никак, fragment серверу не передаётся, насколько я помню

Comment: Не передаётся - это точно.

Comment: Вопрос встал из за необходимости получить токен для своего веб-приложения от вконтакта. В том виде, в котором я описал передаётся токен и id пользователя. Самое смешное то, что этот токен можно свободно скопировать из адресной строки браузера и дальше работать с api вконтакта, но через django - никак. Есть ли альтернативные варианты для получения токена из веб-приложения?

Comment: Вроде в API должен быть способ авторизации специально для сайтов, поищите в документации ВК

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никак, т.к это якорь, а якоря - не индексируются. Обрезается до последнего слеша перед #.