# Запуск функции на N ядрах CPU

Tags: python, python-2.x

Есть функция `F`, на вход которой даётся `2` файла. Она их обрабатывает и сохраняет эти `2` файла уже изменёнными на диск, вместо старых.

Известно число ядер CPU, равное `N`.

Есть список файлов в количестве `M`, из них получен массив пар, используя число сочетаний из `M` по `2`. Этот массив разделён на последовательные задания, каждое из которых содержит `N` непересекающихся пар.

Каким образом в Python организовать вызов этой функции `F` для всех `N` ядер CPU, при условии, что каждый такой многоядерный вызов будет с непересекающимися парами файлов (это уже реализовано в виде подготовленного массива заданий). После обработки, функция сохраняет эти `2*N` файлов, и запускается уже со следующими файлами.

То есть как организовать `вызов функции для N ядер` -> `ожидание завершения работы функции` -> `следующий вызов`?

Необходимо реализовать это без использования каких-либо сложных структур или модулей, вроде многопоточных классов или как там их.

Answer (score -1):

Вариант решения задачи:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool

def loop(s):
    for i in range(10):
        print i,s

x = []
x.append(['1.txt','3.txt'])
x.append(['2.txt','4.txt'])
....

results = Pool().map(loop,x)
pass
```

Исправил, проверил, но всё равно работает только 1 CPU.

Comment: В CPython, только один поток может Питон код исполнять в любое время (поэтому только один CPU будет загружен Питон кодом). Несколько потоков одновременно могут работать только если другие потоки GIL отпустили (ждут ввода/вывода от системы, выполняют вычисления в Си коде, не трогая Питон-интерпретатор). Посмотрите в сторону  пула процессов, к примеру из `concurrent.futures` модуля.

Comment: @jfs да, вы правы

Comment: вот пример кода с использованием пула потоков (чтобы использовать процессы, достаточно импорты поменять) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/705237/23044

Comment: мне кажется, проще будет сделать многократный вызов функции Python с параметрами, ждать окончания работы и вызывать опять с новыми параметрами, например из bat или sh файла (в зависимости от ОС). Просто вызвать сразу 8 экземпляров и получится 8 параллельных процессов

Comment: к чему велосипед изобретать, пул процессов за вас будет ждать окончания выполнения функции, сделает новые вызовы когда ресурсы появятся. Суть сводится к `results = Pool().map(function, many_args)`